# Disk full on Synology NAS, can't connect

Tags: nas, synology

I accidentally filled the entire disk on my Synology DS218 NAS. Normally I would try to delete files, and I can reach it via AFP but I have the recycling bin turned on, so any file I can delete just gets moved there, it does not actually get deleted from the machine.

I cannot connect to it on ports 22 or 5000, the normal ways I would connect to it.

Do you have suggestions for how I can get into the device to clear some disk space and restore normal operation?

Answer (score 1):

1. Restart you NAS
2. Before Synology "Turn On beep" ssh to device
3. `df -h` to get drives
4. Found out drive with use > 99% (probably it is /dev/md0 if deletion of files from volume1 does not help)
5. navigate to `/` (root dir)
6. `sudo du -hs *` list biggest directories/files
7. Delete file that is causing the problem(in my case this was a video file that I tried to copy to USB drive before)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get into the machine even if the disk is full. In my case the default settings were trying to bind to an unexpected IP address. The Synology Assistant app helped me reset the device's settings to an IP address in the DHCP range, which allowed me to connect to it again.